# List as a member of a python class, why is its contents being shared across all instances of the class?

Tags: python, list, class

I have defined a class `Listener` and created a dictionary of `Listener` objects.  Each listener has an `id` to identify them, and a list of `artists` they listen to, `artists = []`.  Adding something to the `artists` list adds it for all instances of the `Listener` class, rather than the referred instance.  This is my problem.

The Listener class is defined as follows:

```
class Listener:
    id = ""
    artists = []

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def addArtist(self, artist, plays):
        print self.id # debugging...
        print "pre: ", self.artists
        self.artists.append(artist)
        print "post: ", self.artists
```

Here is my debugging test code:

```
def debug():
    listeners = {}
    listeners["0"] = Listener("0")
    listeners["1"] = Listener("1")

    listeners["0"].addArtist("The Beatles", 10)
    listeners["0"].addArtist("Lady Gaga", 4)
    listeners["1"].addArtist("Ace of Base", 5)
```

And the output:

```
0
pre:  []
post:  ['The Beatles']
0
pre:  ['The Beatles']
post:  ['The Beatles', 'Lady Gaga']
1
pre:  ['The Beatles', 'Lady Gaga']
post:  ['The Beatles', 'Lady Gaga', 'Ace of Base']
```

My expected output is that the final `addArtist("Ace of Base", 5)` call would result in the output

```
1
pre:  []
post:  ['Ace of Base']
```

Is this a subtlety of Python I'm not understanding?  Why is this the output and how can I get the desired output instead?  Thanks!

Comment: Where could I find the reason of calling the "artists" variable with "self" in the Class? Is the "artists" variable like the static variable in C++ (shared between objects)?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You don't want the members declared inside the class, but just set in the `__init__` method:

```
class Listener:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.artists = []

    def addArtist(self, artist, plays):
        print self.id # debugging...
        print "pre: ", self.artists
        self.artists.append(artist)
        print "post: ", self.artists
```

If you have a class like

```
class A:
  x=5
```

Then x is a member of the class and not a member of instances of that class.  This can be confusing, since python lets you access class members through the instance:

```
>>> a=A()
>>> print a.x
5
```

But you can also access it through the class itself:

```
>>> print A.x
5
```

It would even appear that this works properly:

```
>>> a1=A()
>>> a2=A()
>>> a1.x=6
>>> print a1.x
6
>>> print a2.x
5
```

but what has actually happened is that you've put a new x into the a1 instance, which will be printed instead of the class member, which still has its original value:

```
>>> print A.x
5
```

You only start to see a difference when you have something that can be changed, like a list:

```
class A:
  l=[]

>>> a1=A()
>>> print a1.l
[]
>>> a2=A()
>>> print a2.l
[]
>>> a1.l.append(5)
>>> print a1.l
[5]
>>> print a2.l
[5]
>>> print A.l
[5]
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. So what's the solution to this? Use tuples instead of lists as members?

Comment: @RachitBhargava: Use the __init__ method to set the value.

Comment: It turned out my issue was different. I was passing mutable objects (lists) as arguments to init to set their default value. These mutable objects were being passed as reference and being shared across all instances of the class.

Comment: Any decorator way to solve it? It's so annoying if you have large list or attribute, you have to reset it manually one by one

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a subtlety of Python I'm not understanding?

It's not subtle, it's quite simple; unlike in other languages which confuse the issue, in Python everything you declare inside the class belongs to the class. This is natural, since classes are objects (like everything else), and thus a perfectly valid place to attach things. Thus, all those methods belong to the class (instead of being somehow magically copied to each instance), and so do the data attributes.

> Each listener has an `id` to identify them

Yes, because you attach one to each instance in the `__init__`. This has **nothing to do with** the `id` that belongs to the class - except that when you look up `id` via an instance, the instance's own `id` will be found, hiding the one belonging to the class.

> and a list of artists they listen to, artists = []

When you look up `artists` via the class, however, the class' `artists` will be found, because the instance doesn't have one.

> Adding something to the artists list adds it for all instances of the Listener class

No; it's added *to the class itself*, which is where things are looked for when they aren't found in the instance.

Keep in mind that if you made a direct assignment like `self.artists = []` on an instance later, that instance would get its own list hiding the class' list. Other instances would not, because that code didn't get run on the other instances.