# How to break the link between lists in sibling objects?

Tags: python

I need to create a set of objects of the same class. The example code is:

```
class Model:
    name = ''
    my_values = []

models = []
for i in range(3):
    m = Model()
    m.name = str(i)
    m.my_values.append(i)
    models.append(m)
```

'm.name = str(i)' works perfect, but 'm.my_values.append(i)' does not: it appends all 'i' values to lists of all objects (and I need to add '0' to the first object list, '1' to the second and so long). How to break the ling between lists?

Comment: well it seems I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751554/list-as-a-member-of-a-python-class-why-is-its-contents-being-shared-across-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an `__init__` function for your Model, because your `my_values` is an attribute and it's shared across all instances of the class.

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.my_values = []


models = []
for i in range(3):
    m = Model(i)
    m.my_values.append(i)
    models.append(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happened here is that you set a default value for `my_value` in `Model`, which will create a list at the start of the program. `my_value` won't be re-initialize (create new list) for every new instance of class created and will continue to use the first one, which leads to the unwanted behavior you are observing. To fix this issue, initiate `my_value` inside `__init__` function.

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.my_values = []


models = []
for i in range(3):
    m = Model(name=str(i))
    m.my_values.append(i)
    print(m.my_values)  # prints out [0], [1], [2] respectively
    models.append(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `__init__` as suggested or create a dataclass (https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field                                                                                                     

@dataclass
class Model:
   values : list = field(default_factory=list)     # note you have to use field for mutables
```